# Task Parallel Library and IIS worker Threads?

Tags: c#, iis, task-parallel-library

I want to use Task Parallel Library for some calculation intensive tasks, but I have been told by a colleague there is a huge overhead for IIS creating worker threads.

I am not sure quite what is done when you call Task.Factory.StartNew()...say 100 times. How does IIS handle this? Is is a huge risk, or is there ways to make this very beneficial for an application?

Answer (score 3):

First Tasks != Threads.  You may have many tasks being serviced by few threads (which are already being pooled).

As a general rule, I'm against running long running processes on web servers.  There are tons of problems keeping long running jobs up and you tend to reduce your web servers scalability, especially if you are paralellizing long running, cpu intensive jobs.  Don't forget the optimal number of threads to have running on a machine is equal to the number of "logical" cores.  You want to avoid creating excess threads (each managed thread eats something like a meg in overhead).  Running cpu intensive jobs takes cpu time away from serving requests.

In my opinion the best way to use tpl on a web server, is to use it with the goal in the mind that you are making requests as non blocking as possible, which allows the greatest number of requests to be served with the smallest number of threads.  Keep in mind that many people make the decision that the extra scale gained by having highly asynchronous request handing is not worth the extra complexity.  Depends on your specific case.

So in short, running many long running cpu bound tasks on a web server risks your scalability.  Doesn't really matter if you are using tasks, threads, backgroundworkers, or the threadpool.  It boils down to the same thing.

Comment: Also, writing asynchronous code is made much easier with C# 5's `async`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about the `Task` abstraction is that it abstracts creating threads away. What that means is that the TPL (actually, the `ThreadPool`) can decide what the best amount of actual threads is. Because of this, creating 100 `Task`s most likely won't create 100 `Thread`s. Because of that, you don't have to worry about the overhead of creating `Thread`s.

But it also depends on what kind of `Task`s they are. If you have 100 `Task`s that perform some long IO-bound operations and so they block most of the time, that's not a good use of TPL and your code will be quite inefficient (and you may actually end up with 100 `Thread`s).

On the other hand, if you have 100 CPU-bound, relatively short `Task`s, that's the sweet spot of TPL and you will get good efficiency.

If you are really concerned about efficiency, you should also know that `Task`s do have some overhead. Because of that, in some cases it might make sense to merge multiple `Task`s into one larger one to make the overhead smaller. Or you can use something that already does that: `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For`, if they fit your use case. As another advantage, code using them will be more readable than using `Task`s manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a service to handle this work?  You'll be much better off in terms of scaling and can isolate that unit of work nicely... even if the work is compute-bound.

In my opinion - don't use the `Thread Pool/BackgroundWorker/Thread` in ASP.NET.  In your case, the `TPL` simply wraps the thread pool.  It's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Threading overheads are the same for any host. Has nothing to do with IIS, at least when it comes to performance.

There are other concerns as well. For example, at application shutdown, user threads are rudely aborted.